# using html.begin form, how to do add the value of {id} to the post url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i need to post url to be /controller/action/someID

not sure how to get someID in using the BeginForm helper.

```
html.beginform("controller", "action", formmethod.post)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it will be:

```
Html.BeginForm("Controller","Action",new { someID = Model.SomeID }, FormMethod.Post);
```

...based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493084.aspx) overload from the FormExtensions in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("controller", "action", new { id = 1234 }, FormMethod.Post))
```

That third parameter is routeValues.